# Fastest way to retrieve information from array and display in html

Tags: javascript, performance

I am creating an app in html5 for mobile, and I have all the information of the items inside an array with 887 entries. Each entry have 32 key with values, some with more than one value.

I am using a for loop to iterate the array, and when I find the entry that match the html element it shows the item information with a html block.

I found that it's more efficient to cache the array lenght to use in the for loop. So instead of doing this:

`for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){//code};`

I am doing this which is more fast:

```
var array_len = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < array_len; i++){//code};
```

Another idea that I tested is creating an index for the array to avoid loops, like this:

```
var index = {
  "strawberry": 0,
  "pear": 1,
  "orange": 2,
  "watermelon": 3,
  "fruit_salad": 4,
  "water": 5,
  "orange_juice": 6,
  "pear_juice": 7,
  "strawberry_juice": 8,
  "watermelon_juice": 9,
  "potato": 10,
  "french_fries": 11
}
```

And then call the item info using a function like this:

```
var singleItem = $('.item');
singleItem.each(function() {
  var item = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  var n = index[item];
  var a_items = array[n];
$(this).html(CODE DO DISPLAY THE ITEM INFORMATION HERE)
}
```

So when I use a code like this: `<div class="item watermelon"></div>` it should retrieve the item information without the need to loop through the array.

Below is an example code I wrote to represent the situation, with a short array of items. In the real app, the main array which holds the items information is 887 items long. And I do some for loops inside the other for loop to retrieve informations like `stats` and the `used in` example.

So, it's a for loop inside a for loop.

The question is, there's a more efficient way of doing this?
Because some pages that display one category of items, with aproximatedely 100 items taks 5, 6 seconds to load, and I need it to be more faster.

Edit: Codepen code that shows performance time with both codes:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBVjKV

```js
// icons: https://www.flaticon.com/search/2?word=food&style_id=28
var array = [
  {
    "name": "strawberry",
    "price": "2.00",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"2"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["strawberry_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "pear",
    "price": "1.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["pear_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange",
    "price": "0.80",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"5"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "used_in":["orange_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": "5.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-6"}
    ],
    "used_in":["watermelon_juice","fruit_salad"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "fruit_salad",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "fruit",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"3"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["strawberry","pear","orange","watermelon"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "water",
    "price": "1.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "used_in":["orange_juice","pear_juice","strawberry_juice","watermelon_juice"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "orange_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["orange","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "pear_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["pear","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "strawberry_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["strawberry","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "watermelon_juice",
    "price": "6.50",
    "type": "drink",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
    ],
    "ingredients":["watermelon","water"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "potato",
    "price": "1.00",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "used_in":["french_fries"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png"
  },

  {
    "name": "french_fries",
    "price": "3.50",
    "type": "food",
    "stats": [
      {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
      {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
      {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
    ],
    "ingredients": ["potato"],
    "icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  }


]

var array_len = array.length;
function gen(){
  var allitems = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array_len; i++){
    var item = array[i];
    var name = item.name;
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    allitems += '<div class="item '+name+'"></div>';
  }
  $('.total').html(array_len);
  $('.allitems').html(allitems);
}

function gen2(){
  for (var j = 0; j < array_len; j++){
    var item = array[j];
    var name = item.name;
    var formatted_name = name.replace(/_/g,' ');
    var price = item.price;
    var type = item.type;
    var icon = item.icon;
    var ing = item.ingredients;
    var used_in = item.used_in;
    var stats = item.stats;
    var stats_info = "";
    var ingredients = "";
    var used = "";
    var stat_item = "";
    if(stats != undefined){
      for(var s in stats){
        var stat = stats[s];
        var type = stat.type;
        var val = stat.val
        stat_item += '<div class="stat">'+
          '<i class="'+type+'"></i>'+
          '<span class="stat_val">'+val+'</span>'+
          '</div>'
      }
      stats_info = '<div class="stats_info">'+
        stat_item+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var i in ing){
      var ing_item = ing[i];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      ingredients += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    for(var k in used_in){
      var ing_item = used_in[k];
      var format_ing = ing_item.replace(/_/g,' ');
      used += '<div class="ingredient"><i class="'+ing_item+'"></i>'+
        '<span class="ing_txt">'+format_ing+'</span>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    var ing_block = "";
    if(ing != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="ingredient_txt">Uses:</div>'+
        ingredients+
        '</div>';
    }
    if(used_in != undefined){
      ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';
    }

    $('.item.'+name).html
    ('<div class="items">'+
     '<div class="itemblock">'+
     '<i class="'+name+'"></i>'+
     '<span class="name">'+formatted_name+'</span>'+
     '<span class="price">$ '+price+'</span>'+
     '<span class="type">'+type+'</span>'+
     '</div>'+
     stats_info+
     ing_block+
     '</div>')
  }
}
gen()
gen2()
```

```css
.strawberry{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png);}
.pear{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png);}
.orange{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png);}
.watermelon{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png);}
.fruit_salad{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png);}
.water{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.orange_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png);}
.pear_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png);}
.strawberry_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png);}
.watermelon_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png);}
.potato{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png);}
.french_fries{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png);}
.hunger {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/608/608857.png);}
.thirst {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.bladder {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1402/1402847.png);}

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  font-family: arial;
}
.totalitems {
  display: block;
  background: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.totalitems .total_txt {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.allitems {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 320px;
}
.items {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1px;
}
.itemblock {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.itemblock .items {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.itemblock i{
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
.itemblock .name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: #ffc107;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.stats_info {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.stats_info .stat {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
}
.stats_info .stat i {
  display: flex;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.stats_info .stat .stat_val {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ingredients_block {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 82px;
}
.ingredients_block .usedngredient_txt,
.ingredients_block .ingredient_txt{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75px;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient i {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient .ing_txt {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="totalitems">
  <span class="total_txt">Total items:</span>
  <span class="total"></span>
</div>
<div class="allitems"></div>
<!-- SEE THIS CODE IN FULL PAGE FOR BETTER VISUALIZATION -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're a lot of things you write them better, In my answer I'll write some of them.

## [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

In ES6 you can use template literals in code meaning:

Don't

```
ing_block = '<div class="ingredients_block">'+
        '<div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>'+
        used+
        '</div>';

'<i class="'+name+'"></i>'
```

Do

```
ing_block = `<div class="ingredients_block">
        <div class="usedngredient_txt">Used in:</div>
        used</div>`;

`<i class="${name}"></i>`
```

## [If Condition and Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

1. Don't compare with `undefined` simply you can write this `if(used_in)` instead of this `if(used_in != undefined)`.
2. You can use ternary operator.

## [const and let instead of var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

you can use `const` if your variable won't change through your app, and let if it'll change.

## [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Simply you can do this:

```
const {price, type, icon} = item;
```

instead of this

```
var price = item.price;
var type = item.type;
var icon = item.icon;
```

You also can iterate through your array using map instead of for loop.

## [Object.keys instead of For in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

You can use Object.keys which is more efficient than iterating using for in. [Source](https://codepen.io/dsheiko/details/JdrqXa)

Answer (score 2):

## Don't add markup via `innerHTML`

The reason for the slow down is not looking up the items but rather your method of creating the HTML.

Adding markup to the page via the `innerHTML` property is VERY slow. You should never add content that way.

Add content to a document fragment. When all the content has been created then add it to the page.

To help, create functions to approximate the declarative style of a HTML document.

In the example I create two helper functions.

- `tag(type, properties)` that creates an element adds properties and returns it.
- `append(element, siblings)` Appends children to the element. Importantly returning the parent element so that the call can be nested

To help the declarative style the second and above arguments of `append` are indented one extra step.

Example indentation

```
const createStats = stats =>
  stats.map(stat => 
    append(                                  // appends sid1, 2 to parent
      tag("div", {className: "stat"}),       // parent
        tag("span", {className: stat.type}), // sibling 1
        tag("span", {className: "stat_val"}) // sibling 2
    )
  );
```

Adding content this way will give a noticeable performance increase.

The code formatting for the example stuffed up and If I use the one in the editor it makes a total mess of it so will have to make do with it in at least a readable format.

```js
const query = str => document.querySelector(str);
const tag = (type, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(type), props);
const append = (el, ...sibs) => (sibs.forEach(sib => el.appendChild(sib)), el);

// timeout just so that the array is parsed without needing to be at the top
setTimeout(()=>gen(array));

const createStats = stats =>
  stats.map(stat => 
    append(
      tag("div", {className: "stat"}),
        tag("i", {className: stat.type}),
        tag("span", {className: "stat_val", textContent: stat.val})
    )
  );
const createIngredients = ingredients =>
  ingredients.map(ingredient => 
    append(
      tag("div", {className: "ingredient"}),
        tag("i", {className: ingredient}),
        tag("span", {className: "ing_txt", textContent: ingredient.replace(/_/g,' ')})
    )
  );
const createItem = item => {
  var extras = [];
  if(item.stats){
    extras.push(append(
      tag("div",{className: "stats_info"}),
        ...createStats(item.stats)
    ));
  }
  if(item.ingredients) {
    extras.push(append(
      tag("div", {className:"ingredients_block"}),
        tag("div", {className:"ingredient_txt", textContent:"Uses:"}),
        ...createIngredients(item.ingredients)
    ));
  }     
  if(item.used_in) {
    extras.push(append(
      tag("div", {className:"ingredients_block"}),
        tag("div", {className:"usedngredient_txt", textContent:"Used in:"}),
        ...createIngredients(item.used_in)
    ));
  }
  return append(
    tag("div", {className:"items"}),
      append(
        tag("div", {className:"itemblock"}),
          tag("i", {className: item.name}),
          tag("span", {className: "name", textContent : item.name.replace(/_/g,' ')}),
          tag("span", {className: "price", textContent : "$" + item.price}),
          tag("span", {className: "type", textContent : item.type})
      ),
      ...extras
  );    
}
function gen(array){
  append(
    query(".allitems"),
      append(
        document.createDocumentFragment(), 
          ...array.map(item => append(
              tag("div",{className: "item " + item.name}),
                createItem(item)
          )
        )
     )
  )
  query(".total").textContent = array.length;
}




var array = [
  {
"name": "strawberry",
"price": "2.00",
"type": "fruit",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
  {"type":"thirst","val":"2"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"used_in":["strawberry_juice","fruit_salad"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png"
  },
  {
"name": "pear",
"price": "1.50",
"type": "fruit",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
  {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"used_in":["pear_juice","fruit_salad"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png"
  },
  {
"name": "orange",
"price": "0.80",
"type": "fruit",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"6"},
  {"type":"thirst","val":"5"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
],
"used_in":["orange_juice","fruit_salad"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png"
  },
  {
"name": "watermelon",
"price": "5.50",
"type": "fruit",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
  {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-6"}
],
"used_in":["watermelon_juice","fruit_salad"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png"
  },
  {
"name": "fruit_salad",
"price": "6.50",
"type": "fruit",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
  {"type":"thirst","val":"3"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"ingredients": ["strawberry","pear","orange","watermelon"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png"
  },
  {
"name": "water",
"price": "1.50",
"type": "drink",
"stats": [
  {"type":"thirst","val":"8"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
],
"used_in":["orange_juice","pear_juice","strawberry_juice","watermelon_juice"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png"
  },
  {
"name": "orange_juice",
"price": "6.50",
"type": "drink",
"stats": [
  {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"ingredients":["orange","water"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png"
  },
  {
"name": "pear_juice",
"price": "6.50",
"type": "drink",
"stats": [
  {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"ingredients":["pear","water"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png"
  },
  {
"name": "strawberry_juice",
"price": "6.50",
"type": "drink",
"stats": [
  {"type":"thirst","val":"4"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"ingredients":["strawberry","water"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png"
  },
  {
"name": "watermelon_juice",
"price": "6.50",
"type": "drink",
"stats": [
  {"type":"thirst","val":"6"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-3"}
],
"ingredients":["watermelon","water"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png"
  },
  {
"name": "potato",
"price": "1.00",
"type": "food",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"4"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"used_in":["french_fries"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png"
  },
  {
"name": "french_fries",
"price": "3.50",
"type": "food",
"stats": [
  {"type":"hunger","val":"10"},
  {"type":"thirst","val":"-4"},
  {"type":"bladder","val":"-2"}
],
"ingredients": ["potato"],
"icon": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png"
  }
]
```

```css
.strawberry{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135717.png);}
.pear{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167260.png);}
.orange{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415734.png);}
.watermelon{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415731.png);}
.fruit_salad{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/415/415744.png);}
.water{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.orange_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167612.png);}
.pear_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167623.png);}
.strawberry_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167254.png);}
.watermelon_juice{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/167/167620.png);}
.potato{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135676.png);}
.french_fries{background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135589.png);}
.hunger {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/608/608857.png);}
.thirst {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/135/135662.png);}
.bladder {background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/1402/1402847.png);}

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  font-family: arial;
}
.totalitems {
  display: block;
  background: #131313;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.totalitems .total_txt {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.allitems {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 320px;
}
.items {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1px;
}
.itemblock {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.itemblock .items {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.itemblock i{
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 2px;
}
.itemblock .name {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 2px;
  color: #ffc107;
  width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.itemblock .type {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 15px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.stats_info {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.stats_info .stat {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
}
.stats_info .stat i {
  display: flex;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.stats_info .stat .stat_val {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
.ingredients_block {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 82px;
}
.ingredients_block .usedngredient_txt,
.ingredients_block .ingredient_txt{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75px;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient i {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ingredients_block .ingredient .ing_txt {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="totalitems">
  <span class="total_txt">Total items:</span>
  <span class="total"></span>
</div>
<div class="allitems"></div>
<!-- SEE THIS CODE IN FULL PAGE FOR BETTER VISUALIZATION -->
```